# PHP isset POST radio button set hangs indefinitely

Tags: php, html

I iterate through each question `<input>` set, some questions are radio button answers, some are checkbox..

on POST I inject into database

```
$i = 1;
while($i<6){
  if(isset($_POST['radio' . $i])){
    (MYSQL insert answer)
    i++;
  }
}
```

The site hangs indefinitely and times out on the 'if' line if radio1 does not exist.  (In that case, checkbox1 existed instead, since 1 denotes the question number.)

Reason I did it this way is radio buttons can be injected immediately, while checkbox answers are multi and need to be concatenated together before injecting

I thought an isset should take care of that, not create that problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't increment $i so you're creating an infinite loop.

```
$i = 1;
while($i<6){
  if(isset($_POST['radio' . $i])){
    (MYSQL insert answer);
    $i++; //increment $i
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Don't insert $_POST values directly into sql. Use prepared statements, filtering or something.

Comment: how would I filter or use a prepared statement?

Comment: That depends on how you're working with MySQL. You can either research PDO or a simpler way, depending on the security needs of this site, you can just filter by white list. If you know a $_POST value is only supposed to contain ints then you can remove everything except for ints for example: `$newValue = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_POST['value'])`. It's just an example though. The way you filter is specific to what you are working with. You just can't trust $_POST vlaues and put them directly in sql, because users can easily change them, making you vulnerable to sql injection.